# How to scrape all the test match details in cricinfo

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape all the test match details but it is showing `HTTP Error 504: Gateway Timeout` I am getting the details of test matches but it is not showing this is my code i have used `bs4` to scrape the test match details from cricinfo

**I need to scrape the details of 2000 test matches this is my code**

`import urllib.request as req`

```
BASE_URL = 'http://www.espncricinfo.com'

if not os.path.exists('./espncricinfo-fc'):
    os.mkdir('./espncricinfo-fc')

for i in range(0, 2000):
    
    soupy = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://search.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/match/search.html?search=test;all=1;page=' + str(i)).read())

    time.sleep(1)
    for new_host in soupy.findAll('a', {'class' : 'srchPlyrNmTxt'}):
        try:
            new_host = new_host['href']
        except:
            continue
        odiurl =BASE_URL + urljoin(BASE_URL,new_host)
        new_host = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', new_host).encode('ascii','ignore')
        print(new_host)
        html = req.urlopen(odiurl).read()
        if html:
            with open('espncricinfo-fc/{0!s}'.format(str.split(new_host, "/")[4]), "wb") as f:
                f.write(html)
                print(html)
        else:
            print("no html")
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure why, seems to be working for me.

I made a few changes in the loop through the links. I'm not sure how you're wanting the output to look in terms of writing it to your file, so I left that part alone. But like I said, seems to be working ok on my end.

```
import bs4
import requests  
import os
import time
import urllib.request as req

BASE_URL = 'http://www.espncricinfo.com'

if not os.path.exists('C:/espncricinfo-fc'):
    os.mkdir('C:/espncricinfo-fc')

for i in range(0, 2000):

    i=0
    url = 'http://search.espncricinfo.com/ci/content/match/search.html?search=test;all=1;page=%s' %i
    html = requests.get(url)

    print ('Checking page %s of 2000' %(i+1))

    soupy = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html.parser')

    time.sleep(1)
    for new_host in soupy.findAll('a', {'class' : 'srchPlyrNmTxt'}):
        try:
            new_host = new_host['href']
        except:
            continue
        odiurl = BASE_URL + new_host
        new_host = odiurl
        print(new_host)
        html = req.urlopen(odiurl).read()

        if html:
            with open('C:/espncricinfo-fc/{0!s}'.format('_'.join(str.split(new_host, "/")[4:])), "wb") as f:
                f.write(html)
                #print(html)
        else:
            print("no html")
```

Comment: When i am trying to save the html in the file it is showing me that descriptor 'split' requires a 'str' object but received a 'bytes'

Comment: looking at your code, I see your doing split the with the `new_host` variable. Are you using the code I did above, or your original code? My code has the `new_host` variable stored as a str, so again, it's working ok for me. But again, what are you looking as an output. Are you trying to save each html source code as separate html files?

Comment: ah gotcha. Give me a minute I'll edit my answer to include. are you looking to save the html into individual files?

Comment: yes i want to save all the html files in one folder

Comment: right. but you're looping through 2000. So I'm asking, you're wanting 2000 files in that 1 folder. correct? just trying to make sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184482/discussion-between-tayyab-gulsher-vohra-and-chitown88).

Answer (score 0):

this is usually happen when doing multiple request too fast, it can be the server is down or your connection blocked by server firewall, try increase your `sleep()` or add random sleep.

```
import random

.....
for i in range(0, 2000):
    soupy = BeautifulSoup(....)

    time.sleep(random.randint(2,6))
```